# Set visibility of MarkerClusterer

Tags: visibility, markerclusterer

Trying to toggle the visibility of MarkerClusterer (V3):

```
var hydrantsShowing = true;  

function ToggleHydrants() {  
    var markers = hydrantsClusterer.getMarkers();

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(!hydrantsShowing);
    }

    hydrantsShowing = !hydrantsShowing;
}
```

The markers do toggle but with two problems:
1. The map must be panned a bit to the change can take place.
2. The MarkerClusterer icons (with the numbers) are always there, even after the markers are not visible.

I've also tried using the setMap approach, but with similar behavior:

```
var hydrantsShowing = true;  

function ToggleHydrants() {  
    var markers = hydrantsClusterer.getMarkers();

    if (hydrantsShowing) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(gmap);
        }
    }

    hydrantsShowing = !hydrantsShowing;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it by using *MarkerClustererPlus* instead.

```
var hydrantsShowing = true;  

function ToggleHydrants() {
  var markers = hydrantsClusterer.getMarkers();

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setVisible(!hydrantsShowing);
  }

  hydrantsClusterer.repaint();
  hydrantsShowing = !hydrantsShowing;
}
```

Calling `repaint()` after setting visibility sorted all issues.
The original *MarkerClusterer* don't have such a function.